# CSS angled linear gradient with "nested" gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients, css-gradients

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: desired-gradient]

The light blue lines are just markers. I want an angle from a **fixed px** from the center (off to the left). And I also want the darker blue on the left to be a gradient too.

I can make the angle I need, but I'm stuck on placing it at a fixed point from the center, and making the darker part another angled gradient:

```css
.topbar {
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(28,25,84);
  background: linear-gradient(-63deg, rgba(28,25,84,1) 50%, rgba(20,18,63,1) 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use a [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient)?

Comment: Thanks @MrLister good to know about that, it got me a good enough effect if it wasn't for TermaniAfif going all the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have multipe background like follow:

I made the fixed distance from the center to be `200px` which is the width of one gradient that is shifted by half `200px` from the center:

```css
.topbar {
  height: 150px;
  background: 
    
    /* the markers*/
    linear-gradient(yellow 0 0) 25% /2px 100%,
    linear-gradient(yellow 0 0) 50% /2px 100%,
    linear-gradient(yellow 0 0) 75% /2px 100%,
    /* the needed background*/
    linear-gradient(-63deg, rgba(28,25,84,1) 50%,transparent 0) calc(50% - 100px) 0/200px 100%,
    linear-gradient(rgba(28,25,84,1),rgba(28,25,84,1)) right/50% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, red,blue);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar"></div>
```

You can check this answer for more details on how `background-position` works with percentage values: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731106/using-percentage-values-with-background-position-on-a-linear-gradient/51734530#51734530)

Comment: That's perfect, I didn't manage to get multiple gradients working thanks!

Comment: P.S. is it possible to angle the blue and red gradient 63deg also? @TermaniAfif

Comment: @Dominic yes, simply change the `to bottom` with what you want ... the blue red gradient is easiet one here because it's at the bottom layer and taking all the space