# Responsive background scrolling with constant speed

Tags: css, background-image, css-animations

I want to use a responsive div with a scrolling background image.

In the example I showed it small and large. I want the entire scroll to be constant - so the small div should take x seconds and the large div should also take x seconds (rather than the small one taking less time to complete a whole image pan than the larger one).

I've tried using percentage values in background-position-x but it stops the animation.

```css
.offset {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: slideLeft768px 5s linear infinite;
}

.div1 {
  width: 76.8px;
  height: 57.6px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 768px;
  height: 576px;
}

@keyframes slideLeft768px {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 768px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offset div1"></div>
<div class="offset div2"></div>
```

====================

This is based on Temani Afif's answer:

```css
.offset {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: slideLeft 5s linear infinite;
  width: var(--p);
  --p: 40vw;
  height: 30vw;
}
.div1 {
    --p: 12vw;
    height: 9vw;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    background-position-x: var(--p);
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offset div1"></div>
<div class="offset div2"></div>
```

I made it only use responsive units so it adjusts when you resize the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider CSS variable to make the animation dynamic:

```css
.offset {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: slideLeft768px 5s linear infinite;
  width: var(--p);
}

.div1 {
  --p: 76.8px;
  height: 57.6px;
}

.div2 {
  --p:768px;
  height: 576px;
}

@keyframes slideLeft768px {
  0% {
    background-position: var(--p,0px) 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offset div1"></div>
<div class="offset div2"></div>
```

And since your are using the same image with known dimension you can optimize your code like below:

```css
.offset {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: slideLeft768px 5s linear infinite;
  width: calc(768px * var(--p,1));
  height: calc(576px * var(--p,1));
}

.div1 {
  --p: 0.1;
}

.div2 {
  --p:0.2;
}

@keyframes slideLeft768px {
  0% {
    background-position: calc(768px * var(--p,1)) 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offset div1"></div>
<div class="offset div2"></div>
<div class="offset" style="--p:0.8"></div>
```

You can also check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333) to understand why percentage value won't work and how to make it working.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about css variables like that. It seems it has pretty good browser support (I'm going to use Cordova). Thanks for the link to that answer and your advanced code.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a percentage for the background-position. Since setting the background-size to 100% makes this impossible, we need to set it to another value.

A trick is to use the padding for this. Create a padding right the same dimension than the width. Making the background origin the paddin box, and clip tghe content box, now we can set the size to 50%. Visually, nothing will change. (In case that the extra padding is a problem, you could set a negative margin or a clip-path). And now, the background-position can be moved in percentages:

```css
.offset {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png');
  background-size: 50%;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
  animation: slideLeft768px 5s linear infinite;
}

.div1 {
  width: 76.8px;
  padding-right: 76.8px;
  height: 57.6px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 768px;
  padding-right: 768px;
  height: 576px;
}

@keyframes slideLeft768px {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offset div1"></div>
<div class="offset div2"></div>
```

Comment: I like this trick. We can also consider pseudo element and we can easily get rid of the extra space by hidding the overflow : https://jsfiddle.net/u9yf0gwL/

Comment: Hi I want to use a border in the div so I can't use this method.