# How to add an SVG icon as select dropdown arrow?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying since one hour to manage my HTMl selects and to replace the dropdown icon by an SVG but I don't get it running.

This is my code:

```css
select {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    border-color: blue !important;
    position: relative;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: blue url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='#FFFFFF'/></g></svg>") no-repeat !important;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-position-y: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to adjust the viewbox as the path defined cannot be seen with the actual viewbox. Then remove the extra height definition and also remove the `!important` to be able to set `background-position`

```css
select {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background: blue url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='white'/></g></svg>") no-repeat;
  background-position: right 5px top 50%;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Mr.Jo you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 in case you need  any reference around background-position. Everything is there

Comment: Perfect Afif. Jus a question, how to rotate the arrow on the top when the user clicks the select?