# How to make background image fit correctly inside a board without losing responsiveness

Tags: html, css

I have code in which there is class box,  i have given `backgroundimage` to `class box box1`.

**my problem** is that  the `image is not correctly fitting inside to the board`.

when i `rezize` the window it is `moving upwards`.

How to correct it.

How to make the `image fit correctly inside the board` `without losing responsiveness`?

which is the method to do this, when i try to make it fit inside the board it is not only fitting inside the box, but also losing its responsiveness..

when itry to resize the window the window the image is moving upwards..

```css
html, body {
 background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/K7mpxZG/background9.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55.3vh;
  left: -19.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
 height: 1.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}


.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
      
        <div class="box box1" id="box1"  style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);">
          <p name="values" id="name1" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: try setting your background size to one of either `cover` or `contain` and see which you prefer

Comment: @jhecht i have set the #box1:background-size: `contain`;  but not working

Comment: @jhecht #box1:background-size:` cover`;    worked but` image is moving upwards` when i `rezise the  window` how to `correct it`?

Comment: i will suggest instead of using background image try to create that board in css. thanks.. this might cause other element to behave weirdly thanks.

Comment: @xenio-gracias its a good method thanks for that....now in my snippet, thw `image is moving upwards` when i `rezise the window.`.is there a way to correct it? thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it.. you should use another approach to make this work. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are tackling this the wrong way. I would instead extract the board element from the main background and use it as an element alone:

```css
html {
  background: #afffdc;
}

#container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM15R.jpg) top/contain no-repeat;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 29vh;
  max-width: 20vw;
  max-height: 35vw;
}

.box {
  padding-top: 173%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300) 50% 5%/86% 27% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Here is a transparent version

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to right,pink, lightblue);
}

#container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctB0T.png) top/contain no-repeat;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 29vh;
  max-width: 20vw;
  max-height: 35vw;
}

.box {
  padding-top: 173%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300) 50% 5%/86% 27% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you used background: #afffdc; for html but this is cant be applied for my task,  actually if i use a custom made backgound with buildings and i want to place an image inside that board.. what would i do?    then this method cant be applied know?

Comment: @Jupiter it can apply, simply change the background with what you want and make the broad I have used to have a transparent color instead of #afffdc

Comment: @Jupiter I have updated with a transparent version. I used a gradient that you can easily replace with any image

Comment: @Jupiter yes, I used Gimp to remove the background and then save it as PNG that support transparency

Comment: 50% 5%/86% 27% this denotes?

Comment: @Jupiter `50% 5%` is the background-position (left top) and `86% 27%` is the background-size (width height)

Comment: @Jupiter if you want to understand how the percentage are calculated you can read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Answer (score 1):

If you want your image to cover it's container you can use `background-size: cover;`,

If you want make sure the whole image is being displayed (but being resized if needed), you can use `background-size: contain;`

The above two requires **explicit width & height** in the class `box1`

Comment: I see that your board is part of the background of your body class, when you resize the window, the background image will become smaller but the size of the image on your board will not change. I will suggest you take to take the board out as a separated image.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you give your body a `background-position` according to your requirements. usually centering it is the best choice:

```
background-position: center center;
```

You can see how it works by looking at the snippet. resize the image by its bottom-right handle.

```css
div{
 background-image: url('//unsplash.it/500');
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:center;
 resize:both;
 overflow:auto;
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: when i give `background-position:center;` to body the image is `still moving upwards when i rezize the window`

Comment: if you show your concept in my snippet it would be great