# How to create dash dot and dash dot dot lines and rectanges in CSS

Tags: html, css, border

How to created dash dot and dash dot dot lines and rectangles like

[image: img]

in CSS without using external links to images or other (inline data urls can used if there is no better way).

https://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ozinB

contains some samples like

```
hr.style17:after {
    content: '§';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -14px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #8c8b8b;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

. It uses content and rotate CSS properties, maybe those can used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try a combination of `repeating-linear-gradient` and `radial-gradient`

```css
.dash-dot {
  height:50px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px) 5px 50%/20px 5px repeat-x,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 20px) center/100% 3px no-repeat 
}
.dash-dot-dot {
  height:50px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px) 0px  50%/30px 5px repeat-x,
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px) 10px 50%/30px 5px repeat-x,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 30px) center/100% 3px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash-dot"></div>

<div class="dash-dot-dot"></div>
```

To have a rectangle you need to repeat the same on each side:

```css
.dash-dot {
  height:210px;
  background:
    /*right*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#000,#000 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 20px) calc(100% - 1px) 0/3px 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px) 100% 5px/5px 20px repeat-y,    
    /*left*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#000,#000 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 20px) 1px 0/3px 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px)  0 5px/5px 20px repeat-y,
    /*top*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 20px) 0 1px/100% 3px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px) 5px 0/20px 5px repeat-x,
    /*bottom*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#000,#000 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 20px) 0 calc(100% - 1px)/100% 3px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px) 5px 100%/20px 5px repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash-dot"></div>
```

Comment: This method works for lines only. How to create dash-dot and dash-dot-dot rectangles ?

Comment: @Andrus check the update, you simply need to repeat on each side

Comment: @TemaniAfif please can you explain what is the mean of `5px 50%/20px 5px`

Comment: @DogukanCavus it's `background-position/background-size` so placed at `5px 50%` (top left) with a size of `20px 5px` (width height) .. if you want more detail about how percentage value in background position works you can  read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333