# How to position an image with background-image css property

Tags: css

I was trying to remember something I saw on YouTube. The guy was positioning a background image doing something like this:

```
background-image: url(img/someimg.jpg) 200px 300px;
```

I think the `200px` positions it on the *x-axis* while the other is the *y-axis*. I'm not sure & this doesn't work but it was very similar to this. Can I get some help?

Comment: I would guess that they were using the `background` property to handle both the image, position, etc. Check out [CSS background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Comment: First off, you need make a proper research before posting a question, e.g. with stuff like this, start consulting the docs. at e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). It will save you a lot of time compared to write up questions for every small detail.

Comment: Second, a question need a verifiable sample **within** the question, not to external resources like fiddle etc. only. Now I voted to close and downvoted your last 3 posts. Please reread [ask] so your upcoming posts will comply with SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

There are many background properties like `background-image:`, `background-position:`and all of them can be reduced to one property `background:`. This is useful to save a few bytes and it's faster to write. CSS works exactly the same.

Syntax looks like this:

`background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;`

Check this [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) for more informations

Comment: I know about this but the position value is defined with center, top, bottom etc. I'm looking to move it in pixels so i can set it precisely where I want it

Comment: Position is defined either way. You can use center, right etc or you can use pixels
so it would be like that `background: url() 100px 40px/bg-size bg-repeat .......`

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was allowed. Thank you:)