# 100% height background starting at 50% horizontally

Tags: html, css, background-position

Desired effect: background image with 100% height and horizontally starts at 50% of the element. (The background ends before the right end of the element, or overflows hidden at the right edge of the element depending on the image / element size ratio)

MDN "A `<length>` or `<percentage>`. This specifies the X coordinate relative to the left edge, with the Y coordinate set to 50%."

So I tried to set `background-position:50%`; but oddly this centers the background image horizontally.
Background pivot is set to center when using % values?
Even MDN example shows this behaviour.

I know there is a "hack" with `:after` pseudo element to achieve this effect, I just wonder is this possible with "background" css properties?

Comment: "100% height background starting at **50% horizontally**" "So tried to set background-position:50%; but oddly this **centers the background image horizontally.**"   So it does what you want but you find it odd 50% is the same as center?

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, the desired effect is:  background's **left edge** to be at 50% of the element, while it stays at 100% height.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
If you set here 50% 50% , you will see the background is full centered.

Answer (score 0):

Like you already noticed and as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333) `background-position` with percentage won't behave like you may think.

An idea to achieve this is to consider adjusting `background-origin` like below:

```css
.box {
  padding-left:50%;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069) left/100% auto no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

the trick is to have the `padding` covering half the width and we start placing the background inside the `content-box`

Comment: This pretty close, despite it forces to use add position: relative on the element and position: absolute on it's content.

Comment: @d.gabriel.asa it will depend on the content but as you already found, you can consider pseudo element so it may probably be better than this. I simply tried to find a way with pure background even if it's not really something we should use in production.