# How to animate underline from left to right?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to replicate this transition from uber.design site:

[image: I am trying to replicate this transition from uber.design site]

The thing is that i am stuck at reversing the transition:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use gradient and adjust `background-position` with a delay to obtain such effect:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  background-position: 0 100%; /*OR bottom left*/
  background-size: 0% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition:
    background-size 0.3s,
    background-position 0s 0.3s; /*change after the size immediately*/
}

.un:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%; /*OR bottom right*/
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

In case you want a continuous animation on hover you can try this:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  background-position: right -100% bottom 0;
  background-size: 200% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.un:hover {
  background-position: left -100% bottom 0;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

You can check this answer for more details about how the calculation of the different value is done: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)

---

Another kind of animation

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 33%,#0000 33% 66%,#000 66%);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 300% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.un:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

let's don't forget the basic one:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  background-position: right bottom; /* OR left bottom*/
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.5s;
}

.un:hover {
  background-size: 0% 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

You can find more techniques here: https://dev.to/afif/100-underline-overlay-animation-the-ultimate-css-collection-4p40

Another related article: [Cool Hover Effects That Use Background Properties](https://css-tricks.com/cool-hover-effects-using-background-properties/)

Comment: I noticed that when there is a line break the underline only appears on the bottom. Any fix for that so it follows the line break?

Comment: @FluffyBeing remove inline-block

Answer (score 4):

You'll need your pseudo element to be absolute positioned and use the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector to reproduce this effect.

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.un:not(:hover):after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

Comment: what is the `left: auto` in the `not(hover)` part doing ?

Comment: how would you complete this css, to run on click (for example where on mobile)?

Comment: Attach an event click and use a class instead of the hover selector.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution of all, **without :not selector or gradients**, is to switch between right and left positions such as in the code.

```css
span.un {
  position: relative;
}

span.un::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: black;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}

span.un:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underline me</span>
```