# How to animate a line of a rectangle's diagonals?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am trying add up an animation diagonally. The rectangle height and width I know (dynamically adding up). Now trying to animated a line from N to L, or O to M or other ways.
I tried with svg and increasing the line's x1, y1, x2, y2 but this is getting complicated. Any easier or simpler solution?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can give your lines a `stroke-dashoffset` and animate it to 0. To calculate the values for `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` I've used the [getTotalLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) method to calculate the values for `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`. I hope it helps.

```css
svg{background:#efefef;width:100vh}
rect,line{stroke:black; fill:none}

#om{stroke-dasharray:94.34px;
stroke-dashoffset:94.34px;
animation: om 1s linear forwards;}


@keyframes om {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 70">  
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="50" />
  <line id="om" x1="90" y1="60" x2="10" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

And this is with both lines animated this time with m to o and l to n: just change the values for x1 to x2 and viceversa. The same for y. This will change the direction of the line.

```css
svg{background:#efefef;width:100vh}
rect,line{stroke:black; fill:none}

#mo,#ln{stroke-dasharray:94.34px;
stroke-dashoffset:94.34px;
animation: om 1s linear forwards;}


@keyframes om {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 70">  
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="50" />
  <!--<line id="om" x1="90" y1="60" x2="10" y2="10" />
  <line id="nl" x1="90" y1="10" x2="10" y2="60" />-->
  <line id="mo" x2="90" y2="60" x1="10" y1="10" />
  <line id="ln" x2="90" y2="10" x1="10" y1="60" />
</svg>
```

I'm using the same animation for both `#om` and `#nl`

Comment: This is perfect. The example you added, its O to M, I figured for L to N I changed the line to `<line id="om" x1="10" y1="60" x2="90" y2="10" />`, kind of confused how to make this work with N to L and M to O?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  If you draw the line in the same direction as the first one, then you can re-use the CSS animation: https://jsfiddle.net/0xodvb82/

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. This worked. :)
However https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength doesnt work in IE and safari. :(

Comment: There are other methods to get the size of the line. After all your lines are the hypotenuse in a right angled triangle. This in the case you need to calculate it dynamically.

Comment: Yes there are (I fixed that with `const pathWidth = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(LO, 2) + Math.pow(ON, 2))` but `stroke-dasharray` not working in IE11.
Any polyfill for this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple idea with background coloration. You simply need to increase the `background-size` to draw the lines:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    /*M - O*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),red calc(50% - 2px),
      red calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) top left,
      
    /*N - L*/  
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),#000 calc(50% - 2px),
      #000 calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) bottom left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Change the `background-position` to change the animation start:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    /*M - O*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),red calc(50% - 2px),
      red calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) bottom right,
      
    /*N - L*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),#000 calc(50% - 2px),
      #000 calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) top right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a version without the use of `calc()` that will work with IE. It will be a bit tricky to find the correct values and you will need a `background-position` animation which is also tricky:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    /*M - O*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent 176px,red 176px,
      red 181px,transparent 181px) left 200% top 200%,
      
    /*N - L*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent 176px,black 176px,
      black 181px,transparent 181px) left -100% bottom -100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:200% 200%;
  transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  background-position:0 0,left 0 bottom 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Check this answer for more details about the different values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Comment: This is shaking.

Comment: @DogukanCavus yes in the second example because the background-position is getting recalculated again when the size is changing, so rendring issue