# Changing a css linear gradient animation without freezing the animation

Tags: javascript, css, linear-gradients

I have an linear gradient animation for my website and I would like themes, so I am trying to use javascript to change the color's in the css,
I got it to do something but it freezes the animation when I do so.

```js
function changeBackground() {
   document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB)";
 }
```

```css
body {
 width: 100wh;
 height: 90vh;
 color: #fff;
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
 background-size: 400% 400%;
 -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes Gradient {
     0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
    }

    @keyframes Gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
    }
```

```html
  <a onclick="changeBackground()">Default</a>
  <a onclick="clickHandler()">Fire</a> // This will be implemented at a later time.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change only the `background-image` not the whole `background`. Changing the background will override the `background-size` and will freeze the animation. Better define `background-image` in the CSS also to avoid other issues.

You can also get rid of the prefix versions and simplify the animation like below:

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(-45deg, blue,red)";
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 90vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0%,100% {
    background-position: left
  }
  50% {
    background-position: right
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="changeBackground()">Default</a>
<a onclick="clickHandler()">Fire</a> // This will be implemented at a later time.
```

You can check this answer to understand the simplification and to have more details in case you need different animations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Answer (score 0):

First, since your "a" tag acting as buttons and not as anchors you should use the button element. 
Secondly, make a class with the desired background colors and fire it with the onclick event.
(by the way body width should be on vw and not as you wrote it)

```js
function changeBackground() {
   document.body.classList.add('changeBackground');
 }
```

```css
body {
width: 100vw;
height: 90vh;
color: #fff;
background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
background-size: 400% 400%;
-webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}

@keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}
.changeBackground {
background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, yellow, blue, red, green);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeBackground()">Default</button>
```

***Just another approach.

Good Luck!

Comment: I would better consider background-image in your both classes so you avoid repeating all the properties (you can already delete the animation)

Answer (score 0):

## The Fix

This is because you are overriding the values of your animation. In CSS inline styles have a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than linked styles, and the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) attribute is a shorthand that sets both `background-image` and `background-position`. The styles you're applying via JavaScript are setting new values with **higher specificty** than your animation keyframes. To fix this, set `backgroundImage` rather than `background`.

```js
function changeBackground() {
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB)";
 }
```

```css
body {
width: 100wh;
height: 90vh;
color: #fff;
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
background-size: 400% 400%;
-webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}

@keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}
```

```html
<a onclick="changeBackground()">Default</a>
<a onclick="clickHandler()">Fire</a> // This will be implemented at a later time.
```

## An Improved Approach

Better yet - use CSS classes to apply the change in styles rather than through JavaScript and avoid the specificity battle altogether. This how CSS is intended to be used.

Also worth mentioning a `<button>` is a more appropriate element to use for behavior, as anchors are for sending the user somewhere.

Though, if you're pulling the linear gradient values programmatically this may not be an option.

```js
function setDefault() {
  document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('class', '');
};

function clickHandler() {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('fire');
};
```

```css
body {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 90vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

.fire {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000, #efefef, #ff0000, #efefef);
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}

@keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setDefault()" tyle="button">Default</buttopn>
<button onclick="clickHandler()" tyle="button">Fire</buttopn>
```