# How to animate background-position using percentages when background-size is 100%?

Tags: css, css-animations, background-position, background-size

Take the following example:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    background: #222222;
    position: relative;
    flex: 640px 0 0;
    height: 360px;
}

@keyframes stars {
 0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
 100% {
        background-position: -100% 0;
    }
}

#stars {
    animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="stars"></div>
</div>
```

The idea here is to animate the stars moving from one side to the other by changing the background position **using percentages**. I can get this working using `px`, for instance, but that requires me to know the width in advance (in this case `640px`) and if I want to change the width/height of `#main` I need to change the animation values and I want to avoid that, thus the percentages. Also, I want to acomplish this with CSS only, no JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the size of the background smaller and use scale to rectify this by increasing the size of the container. Then you will be able to animte the background like you want:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  background: #222222;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#stars {
  animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png');
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(2);
}

@keyframes stars {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="stars"></div>
</div>
```

Here is another idea without scale where you also make the element twice bigger using `right:-100%` or `left:-100%` or `width:200%`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  background: #222222;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#stars {
  animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png');
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: -100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes stars {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="stars"></div>
</div>
```

Here is another simplification considering pseudo element:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
#main:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:-100%;
  bottom:0;
  animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
  background: 
    url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png') left/50% 100%,
    #222222;
}

@keyframes stars {
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

In all the case, the trick is to avoid having `100% 100%` in the `background-size` or it will be impossible to animate using percentage.

---

I have used `left`/`right` for simplification which is equivalent to `0% 50%`/`100% 50%`. Simply switch between both to change the direction.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

---

And since we have made the size of the container bigger, we can also animate it using translate to have better performance:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
#main:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:-100%;
  bottom:0;
  animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
  background: 
    url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png') left/50% 100%,
    #222222;
}

@keyframes stars {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

With scaling:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
#main:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform:scaleX(2);
  transform-origin:left;
  animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
  background: 
    url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png') left/50% 100%,
    #222222;
}

@keyframes stars {
  100% {
    transform:scaleX(2) translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

In the other direction

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:0;
}
#main:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform:scaleX(2);
  transform-origin:right;
  animation: stars 10s linear infinite;
  background: 
    url('https://i.imgur.com/nyFndCj.png') left/50% 100%,
    #222222;
}

@keyframes stars {
  100% {
    transform:scaleX(2) translateX(50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```