# Math question percentage of circle percentage in javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

**Edit 2:**
The following is the code i was looking for

```
var curr_val_calc = curr_val * 0.03125 * 32;
var perc_of_max = (curr_val_calc / max_value * 100).toFixed(3)
```

**Edit:** The circle is a health bar indicator for a game, each time the game does a push the current health value updates.

Consider I have a circle with a percentage range of 0% (full) to -17% (empty). I would like my circle to change in `0.53125%` increments which would be 32 different times in 17%.

I will have a variable for **max value** and **current value**. I want to write a function that will determine the percentage of the circle based on the current value.

I need to figure out how to ***calculate***  the **`50_PERCENT_OF_MAX_VALUE, 25_PERCENT_OF_MAX_VALUE, ...`** and so on based on the following example. And have 32 different options for `background-position-y: 0%;`.

Something like:

```
// These variables are dynamic
var max_value = "700";
var curr_value = "659";

// if ( 659 >= 350 )
if ( curr_value >= 50_PERCENT_OF_MAX_VALUE) {
  $('#orb').css('background-position-y', '-8.5%');
}
// if ( 659 >= 175 )
if ( curr_value >= 25_PERCENT_OF_MAX_VALUE) {
  $('#orb').css('background-position-y', '-4.25%');
}
if ( curr_value >= 3.125_PERCENT_OF_MAX_VALUE) {
  $('#orb').css('background-position-y', '-0.53125%');
}
```

And so on....

Below is the code for my circle:

```css
#orb {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent url(https://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/9273158/thumb/1.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="orb" style="background-position-y: 0%;"></div>
```

Comment: The maths makes sense, but your description of what you're trying to do does not. Can you please edit the question to make the goal clearer.

Comment: I hope the edit is a little bit more clear

Comment: The circle is a health bar indicator for a game, each time the game does a push the current health value updates.

Comment: Your question flows in `x-direction`, and your description flows in `negative x-direction`. Here's a mathematics solution for you.

Comment: More efficient would be background-color to not fetch image, but then you would need two elements or gradient with color stop at desired position.

Comment: this will probably help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Comment: Why are the health values not 100% for full and 0% for empty?

Comment: Isn't it just:   3.125_PERCENT_OF_MAX_VALUE = max_value * 0.03125   ? It would probably be best to store max_value as a number, not a string too.

Comment: @aptriangle `max_value * 0.03125 * 32` is what i was looking for thank you, make it a answer and i will mark it as correct