# How to Animate a Skeleton Screen with a CSS Mask

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to add a subtle shimmer animation to the skeleton that looks like [this one](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/shimmer). I currently have a screen that looks like this (See on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/muhammadrehansaeed/pen/KKzBedY)):

[image: Skeleton screen]

I'm trying to write a skeleton component that can accept an SVG like so:

```
<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
  <svg width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g opacity="0.8">
      <rect x="79" y="32" width="154" height="11" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/>
      <rect width="179" height="20" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/> 
      <rect x="79" y="52" width="84" height="11" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/>
      <rect y="26" width="67" height="42" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.07"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I'm using to animate a shimmer above the SVG:

```
.skeleton {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.skeleton::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(243, 242, 241) 0%, rgb(237, 235, 233) 50%, rgb(243, 242, 241) 100%) 0px 0px / 90% 100% no-repeat rgb(243, 242, 241);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  
  animation-name: skeleton-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes skeleton-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use some sort of mask as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fast/pull/3770#issuecomment-685942763), so that the animation shimmer only takes place over the SVG.

Comment: this may help ... svg gradient mask ... about 1/2 way down the page ... https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/animating-clipped-elements-svg/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55709137/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to use the `SVG` as a `mask-image` and let the linear gradient `background-position` be updated:

example (update with your own gradient colors).:

```css
.skeleton {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 233px;
  height: 68px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(143, 142, 141) 0%, rgb(237, 235, 233) 50%, rgb(143, 142, 141) 100%) 0px 0px / 100% 100% rgb(243, 242, 241);
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  margin: 1em;
  animation: linearAnim 2s infinite linear
}

@keyframes linearAnim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 230px 0px;
  }
}

/* demo purpose only */
.skeleton + .skeleton {

  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(143, 142, 141,0.75) 0%, rgba(237, 235, 233, 0.75) 50%, rgba(143, 142, 141, 0.75) 100%) 0px 0px / 100% 100% rgba(243, 242, 241, 0.5);
  }
  .skeleton.blue {
  background-color:blue;
  }
  .skeleton.red {
  background-color:red;
  }
  .skeleton.yellow {
  background-color:yellow;
  }
  .skeleton.green {
  background-color:green;
  }
  .flex {display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;box-sizing:border-box;padding-top:0.6em;font-size:10px;color:#fff8;}
body {background:#bee; display:grid;grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, 300px);}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton blue" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton red" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton yellow" aria-busy="true"></div>
<div class="skeleton green flex" aria-busy="true">On its way ...</div>
```

here is a similar question with different method [CSS animation, only render overlay on specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457612/css-animation-only-render-overlay-on-specific-elements/56460124)

---

#### edit

if the requirement is to have your SVG inside the HTMl, you may give it an ID and do the encoding part on the fly

```js
// https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript.html

let svg = document.getElementById("mask").outerHTML
let sk =document.querySelector(".skeleton");
let encodedString = btoa(svg);
sk.setAttribute("style", " -webkit-mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64," + encodedString + "')");
```

```css
.skeleton {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 233px;
  height: 68px;
  background: linear-gradient( to right, rgb(143, 142, 141) 0%, rgb(237, 235, 233) 50%, rgb(143, 142, 141) 100%) 0 0 /  200% 100%   rgb(243, 242, 241);
  margin: 1em;
  animation: linearAnim 1.25s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes linearAnim {
 
  100% {
    background-position: -200% 0;
  }
}

#mask {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
<svg id="mask" width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g opacity="0.5">
      <rect x="79" y="32" width="154" height="11" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
      <rect width="179" height="20" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/> 
      <rect x="79" y="52" width="84" height="11" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
      <rect y="26" width="67" height="42" rx="2" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Since I'm trying to build a component, I'd like for users of my component to pass an arbitrary SVG file in via a slot e.g. `<skeleton><svg>...</svg></skeleton>` instead of hard coded in CSS.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed you may give a try to `-webkit-mask-image: url("#SVG_ID");}` , but you'll find out you better off use clip-path from an  clipPath SVG  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path. from ther , bg position animation works the same. You would have to rethink the SVG way to build its shape

Comment: Your edit is very close to what I'm looking for. The only issues are that animating `background-position` is slow and you're also having to set a specific width in the animation. Is there a way to solve these issues?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed animation-timing can be reset to your needs, background-size and background-position can also be used to tune it . I modified the second snippet. For the size, your svg is `width="233" height="68"` which the size of the mask :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *need* to use SVG, then this would be a little easier in HTML.  But here's how to do it with SVGs.

```css
.shimmer-rect {
  animation-name: skeleton-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes skeleton-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(2000px);
  }
}

.skeleton {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include this once somewhere in your HTML -->
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="shimmer" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="2000" spreadMethod="repeat">
      <stop offset="15%" stop-color="rgb(237,235,233)"/>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="rgb(243,242,241)"/>
      <stop offset="35%" stop-color="rgb(237,235,233)"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="shimmer-mask">
      <rect x="79" y="32" width="154" height="11" rx="2" fill="white"/>
      <rect width="179" height="20" rx="2" fill="white"/> 
      <rect x="79" y="52" width="84" height="11" rx="2" fill="white"/>
      <rect y="26" width="67" height="42" rx="2" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <g id="skel" mask="url(#shimmer-mask)">
      <rect class="shimmer-rect" x="-2000" width="3000" height="100%" fill="url(#shimmer)"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>


<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
  <svg width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68"> <use xlink:href="#skel"/> </svg>
</div>

<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
  <svg width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68"> <use xlink:href="#skel"/> </svg>
</div>

<div class="skeleton" aria-busy="true">
  <svg width="233" height="68" viewBox="0 0 233 68"> <use xlink:href="#skel"/> </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to build a reusable Vue/React component e.g. `<skeleton><svg>...</svg></skeleton>`. Is it possible to move some of the shimmer logic up into the CSS and leave the SVG alone?

Comment: If you mean the `<linearGradient>`, then no, that can't be moved to CSS. And I don't think there are any browsers that support CSS gradients on SVG elements. However the `<linearGradient>` only needs to appear once on the page. Just put it somewhere in your page inside a `<svg width="0" height="0"></svg>`. It'll reduce the amount of HTML a bit.

Comment: In fact, most of the SVG only needs to appear once on the page. And you can use a minimal little SVG for each instance of the skeleton. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to create a css skeleton shimmer:

Create a simple class which you then apply to an HTML table and then you can use the HTML to shape / size your skeleton, like so:

```css
@keyframes preloadAnimation {
    from {background-position: 100% 0}
    to {background-position: -80% 0}
}

.shimmer{background: linear-gradient(to right, #dedede 8%, #f3f3f3 18%, #dedede 33%);
     background-size: 200% 50px;
     animation: preloadAnimation 2s infinite;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     width:100%
   }

.shimmer td{background:transparent;border:2px solid white;height:18px}
.shimmer td.white{background-color:white}
```

```html
<table class=shimmer>
          <tr><td style='height:30px'></td><td colspan=2 class=white></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan=3 style='height:12px' class=white></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan=2></td><td class=white></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan=3 style='height:12px' class=white></td></tr>
          <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
          <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan=3 style='height:12px' class=white></td></tr>
          <tr><td style='height:30px'></td><td colspan=2 class=white></td></tr>
        </table>
```