# Aligning multiple SVG to surround elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

#### Hello, I'm having issues with styling multiple SVGs that cut through contents in a way so that they align properly even on window resize.

This is the result I want.
[image: desired effect]
It's one single SVG that wraps between two elements.

#### Here is my attempt at it using FlexBox

As shown above, I divided each path into their own SVG component (SvgIn, SvgMid, SvgOut)

so SvgIn and SvgOut may stretch vertically along with their adjacent element.

```
<div
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#A0A0A0",
    margin: "50px"
  }}
>
  <section style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <SvgIn style={{ height: "100%", alignSelf: "flex-start" }} />
    <ContentOne
      style={{
        margin: "auto",
        width: "100px",
        height: "250px",
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }}
    />
  </section>

  <SvgMid style={{ alignSelf: "center", width: "100%", height: "auto" }} />

  <section style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <ContentTwo
      style={{
        margin: "auto",
        width: "300px",
        height: "150px",
        backgroundColor: "blue"
      }}
    />
    <SvgOut style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", height: "auto" }} />
  </section>
</div>
```

#### The result isn't great

[image: demonstration of align multiple svgs going wrong]

- The width of SvgIn and SvgOut aren't responsive unlike SvgMid where it's always 100% width of the parent, so it looks broken.
- Despite 100% height, SvgIn and SvgOut does not stretch fully to fill the their own section container. (Turning `preserveAspectRatio` off does work but is there another way)
- If possible, can this be achieved without extract each path in the svg but manipulate the paths directly.

The SVG components and full snippet is in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kalam-wqr0v)

Thank you for helping out this confused beginner.

Comment: in case you are intrested here is a CSS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56188930/8620333 .. simply need to do it from top to bottom

Comment: @TemaniAfif The CSS solution with the one that retains transparency and gradient seems to work but the lines aren't as smooth. The curves will look very aliased/jagged since there are no line at all, but a mask over the background gradient.