# How to fill curves with background in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add curved lines to my webpage, I've figured out how to do curved lines in CSS through this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002560/how-to-create-curve-lines-css-div) but I can't think of how to fill them properly to match the background using only CSS.

This is the rough sketch:
[image: what is intended]

And the results I aim for:
[image]

I know how to make the curved lines, but not how to fill the space below them (green space in first image)

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/a/43891983/13586781 someone already answered this.

Comment: I'm sorry but the link you've attached shows how to make the curves, not fill them? Or is there a point I've missed?