# Rem units in JS are calculated?

Tags: javascript, css

```
const someHeight = "3rem";
example.style.padding = `calc(${someHeight} + 2rem)`;
```

Results in the inline style of: `padding: calc(5rem)`.

**My expected result** is: `padding: calc(3rem + 2rem)`.

It seems the result of `calc()` is calculated by JS. Why is this happening? And if JS can add two rem values, why doesn't this work?

```
example.style.padding = `${someHeight} + 2rem`
```

Comment: `calc()` is a CSS function not a JavaScript function

Comment: @lastr2d2, yes, this is why I am confused.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56229772/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems the result of calc() is calculated by JS.

Not by the JavaScript code, no; by the browser. The `style` object is not a simple container. When you assign to properties on it, the browser processes those and when you look at their values, those are not necessarily in the same form as when you assigned them. For instance, if you do `example.style.color = "#020202"` and then look at `example.style.color`, you're likely to see `rgb(2, 2, 2)` or similar (it varies by browser):

```js
const example = document.getElementById("example");
example.style.color = "#020202";
console.log(example.style.color); // rgb(2, 2, 2) on Chrome
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

This is the same sort of thing, if you assign `calc(3rem + 2rem)`, since those units are the same, it's not surprising that when giving the value back to you, the browser has combined them:

```js
const example = document.getElementById("example");
example.style.padding = "calc(3rem + 2rem)";
console.log(example.style.padding); // calc(5rem) on Chrome
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

You can see that it's not the JavaScript code that's doing it by writing the result to a variable:

```js
const example = document.getElementById("example");
const someHeight = "3rem";
const padding = `calc(${someHeight} + 2rem)`;
console.log(padding);               // calc(3rem + 2rem)
example.style.padding = padding;
console.log(example.style.padding); // calc(5rem) on Chrome
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: This makes sense! The only thing that still surprises me is that the processing by the browser is only successful when the units are wrapped in `calc()`.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber - That's the only place they're valid. `3rem + 2rem` isn't a valid length value, but `calc(3rem + 2rem)` is. :-)