# Add a partial background inside div

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a div with a partial background, example:

[image]

I tried applying margin in white, but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written any code? If so, can you add it to your post?

Comment: @vonajots as mentioned, I tried using margin/padding. Don't have the idea what else I could do. Is necessary to show the code for a simple margin?

Comment: what you want to achieve? why not having a nested  div with the background?

Comment: This div it's just an "illustration", to say that a video is going to appear there. After add dynamically the video object, I don't want this div background to appear behind the video if the video is smaller.

Comment: all this need to belong to the question, we cannot imagine you will be using a video with that "illustration" so try to put more details in your question

Comment: What is the background? An image? A gradient?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. I wanted to know if this was possible only using css and background color, without image.

Comment: *I wanted to know if this was possible* --> but we are not understanding what you want. It's clear only for you ... there is nothing called *partial background*. we need more details about what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write any code in question. So i writing example Html and CSS code now. I hope this code will has solve your problem.

```css
body{
background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
.bg-container{
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9aDy.jpg");
width:250px;
height: 250px;
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 200px;
background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background-size: width height;` and `background-position: x  y;` to  specify the space the background occupies within the div.

A gradient is an image, so you can add one and manipulate it as a color. Use `background-color` to specify the background you want to use behind it. `background-repeat: no-repeat` ensures that it is used only once.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 80% 80%;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
background-color: black;
```

The background-position values specify the horizontal and vertical positions, respectively. Use 50% 50% to center it.

Comment: *The background-position values specify the distance from the left and top border of the div* --> this is not true when it comes to percentage values (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333)

Comment: From w3schools.com: "The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is 100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. . Default value is: 0% 0%."

Comment: and where it says: *the distance from left and top* in this quotation?

Comment: If 0% is the left border and 100% is the right border, then 20% is 20% in distance from the left border.

Comment: sorry but you interpretation is wrong, it's not a *distance*. Check the link I shared to better understand how percentage values works (you can also run some tests and you will see)