# Push background position off screen to the left

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

[image]

The background is the red rectangle
The screen is the black rectangle

(Fig1) is the original position of my background

If I want to push it all the way to the right, off-screen (Fig2), I just set

```
background-position: 100vw;
```

This works perfectly fine. However I want to do the same in reverse, push the background off screen to the left (Fig4). If I set the background-position like so

```
background-position: -100vw;
```

It does not work as expected (Fig3- bug) since the original point of background (0,0) is always top-left.

Could you guys show me how to achieve Fig4 position? Thanks

Comment: did you try to use % instead of vw?

Comment: Yes, it does not work.

Comment: could you provide an example in some code sandbox?

Comment: can u plz send the entire code?

Comment: Make a fiddle http://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the reference and use `right 100vw`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200) right 99vw bottom 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Related question for more details: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333). You will also find a generic way to make the background outside of its container in the section **Special cases**

Comment: You make my day

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper and then transform the background here I set to -90% but you can set to -100%:

```
<div class="body-bg"></div>
<div class="content"><h1>Some content</h1></div>

.body-bg {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateX(-90%); 
}
.content {
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/alexplummer/pen/JjPavBe