# Solid color as background for top 5% of the page, images for the rest

Tags: css, background, gradient

Is it possible to use CSS to make the background of the top 5% of a page a solid color, and two different background images for the remaining 65% and 30%?

This is how I need it to look:

[image]

Comment: Yes but it could be done in many ways. Can you show us what you've worked on?

Comment: I had this previously (only two colors, no images): .pageWrapper{
 background:color1;
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, color1 4%, color2 4%, color2 4%, color2 30%);
}  I tried replacing color2 with url(path), but that did not work.  I tried the path without quotes, with single and double quotes, as well as relative and absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Edit 2: So there are numerous ways to accomplish this.

1. **Pseudo elements:** I think this is the best method, as it avoids extra elements in the markup and allows good control of scaling/cropping. *Example below.*
2. **Multiple containers:** Works just like pseudo elements, but with the added disadvantage of extra elements in the markup. The best support across older browsers, but these days, pseudo elements are quite well supported. *Example below.*
3. **Multiple backgrounds:** This may be suitable for solid colors or gradients, but for most images scaling and cropping will be problematic if using percentages for size. *Example below.*

---

### 1. Pseudo Elements

Just add `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to the pagewrapper, supply background images, and position accordingly.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.pagewrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.pagewrap::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 5%;
 left: 0;
 height: 65%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/nckTrT6T/21.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
.pagewrap::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/qvDLXqB3/Optical-Illusion-Brain-washer-27.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagewrap">
</div>
```

---

### 2. Multiple Containers

Just replace the pseudo elements in above example with container divs in the html.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.pagewrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.mid65 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5%;
 left: 0;
 height: 65%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/nckTrT6T/21.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
.btm30 {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/qvDLXqB3/Optical-Illusion-Brain-washer-27.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagewrap">
    <div class="mid65"></div>
    <div class="btm30"></div>
</div>
```

---

### 3. Multiple Background Images

Use multiple background images:
`background-image: url("image1.jpg"), url(image2.jpg);`

then use the same comma separated syntax
for `background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;` *(same value need not repeat)*
and `background-size:  100% 30%, 100% 65%;`,
etc..

The background position is the tricky part though, because it doesn't seem to work as one might expect *(Temani Afif kindly provided a very informative [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333) in the comments below )*. But this seems to achieve the desired result of 5% 65% 30%:
`background-position: bottom left, 0% 15%;`

> Edit: Replaced gradients with actual images so you can see how **image stretching may be an issue** with this method. *More suitable for solid colors or gradients.*

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.pagewrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/qvDLXqB3/Optical-Illusion-Brain-washer-27.jpg"), url("https://i.postimg.cc/nckTrT6T/21.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 30%, 100% 65%;
  background-position: bottom left, 0% 15%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagewrap"></div>
```

Comment: when it comes to solid color you can simplify the gradient to `linear-gradient(red,red)` and you don't have to repeat all the `no-repeat`, only one is enough for all.

Comment: and check this if you want to understand the logic behind the percentage value of background-positiion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Comment: I improved the answer. Added additional methods: Pseudo elements & Multiple containers. Both of which are probably more suitable when it comes to percentage based scaling as per original question. I also added the link Temani provided above regarding background positioning.

Comment: for the pseudo element one I would better consider `bottom:0` for the after rather than top value and don't forget `left:0` for both

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. `bottom` is probably better. I figured left was not needed, but I guess for `:after` introducing content would change that. I edited them. For the pseudos and multi-containers, would it be wise to make the 65% heights 66% so that there is a bit of overlap? It works fine as is, so I suppose it shouldn't be needed, but I wouldn't be surprised to see a fine gap in some quirky browsers.

Comment: In this case, I am unable to control HTML (the site is a PHP-based forum) and am only able to style the background via an additional CSS file.  So solutions 1 and 2 (pseudo elements and multiple container) are not applicable here.  The instructions in solution 3 are not very clear.  The top needs to be a solid color and the remaining 2 backgrounds images.  It's probably also not a good idea to set height, margin and padding for html and body elements, because it could interfere with the forum's style.