# How to make a picture using only one element - div?

Tags: css

The designer designed the logo. It will need to be used in a variety of conditions. To make it as convenient as possible, layout it with a single HTML element in pure CSS.

You cannot use pictures (even through data:uri).

I tried to use pseudo elements, but it doesn't work.
**Notes**

- Overall width: 180px
- Overall height: 180px
- Yellow section height: 90px
- White section width: 90px
- Rounding radius: 9px
- Colors:
- - black: #0c0c0c
- - yellow: #f8e34b
- - white: #eeedef
- shadow: #c8c8c8, 178 degrees

```css
div {  
  width: 180px;  
  height: 180px;  
}

div:before{
 content:"";
 width: 180px;
 height: 90px;
 background: #f8e34b;
}

div:after {
 content: "";
 width: 90px;
 left: 0;
 height: 90px;
 background: #eeedef;
}

div:after{
 content: "";
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 right: 0;
 background: #0c0c0c;
}
```

```html
    
        <div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: you can easily do a small *effort* with pseudo element to start

Comment: I can't use anything, **only** tidy `CSS`

Comment: pseudo element is CSS

Comment: I tried to use them, but it doesn't work...

Comment: add inline-block to pseudo element

Comment: don't remove the logo, the question is all about making it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple background can do this:

```css
.box {
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  border-radius:9px;
  background:
     linear-gradient(#f8e34b,#f8e34b)   top /100% 50%,
     
     linear-gradient(178deg,#c8c8c8 30%, transparent 70%) 
      0 calc(50% + 4px) /50% 8px,
      
     linear-gradient(#0c0c0c,#0c0c0c) bottom right/50% 50%,
     
     #eeedef;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Related to understand the different values: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a css pseudo before and after element. Your code would be:

```css
div { 
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #eeedef;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f8e34b;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #c8c8c8;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:  #0c0c0c;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```

However, I have no experience in diagonal shadows, so the example does not include this part.