# CSS Shape masking with image

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

Is it possible to mask the shapes of a div with this image ?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have done so far, using the SVG tag. But it isnt giving me the exact output:

[image]

Code

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 643 525">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <rect width="150" height="200" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:5" />
      <rect x="160" y="100" width="150" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:5" />
      <rect x="50" y="210" width="100" height="80" />
      <rect x="160" y="210" width="225" height="190" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image width="643" height="343" clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="../assets/images/crain.png" x="-50"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Other than changing the coordinates, and recognising that you need a polygon instead of a rectangle for the upper left square, what did you want our help with, what’s the problem you’re having?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica , The the original image the bottom right image is overlapping with the top right image ,I am not able to recreate that ,Because the stoke property doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS mask you can do this:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:grey;
}  
img {
  --_m:
    /* top right part*/
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) calc(82% + 10px) calc(33% - 10px)/35% 25%,
    /* bottom left part*/
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) calc(34% - 10px) calc(80% + 10px)/25% 25%,
    /* Top left part */
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) top left/calc(50% - 10px) calc(50% + 30px),
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) top left/calc(50% + 10px) calc(50% - 10px),
    /* Bottom right part*/
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) bottom right/50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask: var(--_m);
          mask: var(--_m);
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
          mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1028/300/300" >
```

You can add CSS variables to control the gap

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:grey;
}  
img {
  margin:5px;
  --g: 10px; /* the gap */
  --_m:
    /* top right part*/
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) calc(84.5% + var(--g)) calc(33.5% - var(--g))/35% 25%,
    /* bottom left part*/
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) calc(34% - var(--g)) calc(80% + var(--g))/25% 25%,
    /* Top left part */
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) top left/calc(50% - var(--g)) 60%,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) top left/55% calc(50% - var(--g)),
    /* Bottom right part*/
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) bottom right/50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask: var(--_m);
          mask: var(--_m);
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
          mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1028/300/300" style="--g:20px">

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/90/250/250" >

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/102/200/200" style="--g:4px" >
```

[image: CSS multiple mask with rectangular shape]

To understand the trick use the gradient as background on a div element to see the puzzle. Since I am using white color, the mask will show only the gradient part:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:grey;
}  
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid;
  --g:10px; /* the gap */
  background:
    /* bottom left part*/
    linear-gradient(red,red) calc(84.5% + var(--g)) calc(33.5% - var(--g))/35% 25%,
    /* bottom left part*/
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(34% - var(--g)) calc(80% + var(--g))/25% 25%,
    /* Top left part */
    linear-gradient(green,green) top left/calc(50% - var(--g)) 60%,
    linear-gradient(yellow,yellow) top left/55% calc(50% - var(--g)),
    /* Bottom right part*/
    linear-gradient(purple,purple) bottom right/50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

To understand the logic behind all the percentage value I am using check this: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)