# How to initialize the starting point of a background image in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image to my web page. The image that I want to use has around 20% transparent padding on all four sides. What attribute should I use so that the background image has an edge-to-edge fit (avoiding the transparent part)?

```
body{
    background-image: url("bg.png");
    background-size: 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Try using `background-position: center; background-size: 125%;`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333

Comment: Sounds a bit hacky what you are trying to do. Maybe it is better solution to edit image and get rid of that transparent padding in Photoshop? Then your problem solved without extra lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can change background image size, and fix them to center:

```
body{
    background-image: url( "bg.png" );
    background-size: 60% 60%; /* 100% - 40% (top/left + bottom/right paddings) */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I prefer to add a container element to the page and avoid using `body` for background images when I need to exercise finite control over display and positioning. This would be my solution:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ocwmu62/)

**Markup**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="media"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**SCSS**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  .media {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    background: {
      image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cYNlJYQI3Uw/maxresdefault.jpg");
      position: center center;
      size: cover;
      repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I use a CSS reset to remove automatic `margin`/`padding` on the `body` element, and that I allow `body` to fill the entire viewport.

The `container` class fills the `body` element with `width` and `height` set to `100%`. I use the CSS `background-size` property to cover the container, then I use the `transform` property to scale `container`.

There are many ways to achieve this effect. Alternately, using a `background-image` property on the `body` tag will allow me to use `background-size` to scale the image to obfuscate the image's transparent padding as you described, but it is more difficult to center the image within the container.