# CSS gradient with arc

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I've created a vertical linear gradient down a long page with

```
.background {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#0e1a34, #5e7481, #a0947a, #c17a5c, #ada7cb, #d7e8fd, #d7edf0);
}
```

Of course, it is linear and vertical, each color spaced equally in a div that is something like 100vw x 1000vh (the length will vary).

But I'd like each of the colors to gently arc upward across the page (think the darkening vignetting that happens in photographs of the sky), but remain equally spaced down the length of the page and maintain their subtle gradient blending.

Here is an exaggerated example:

[image]

I experimented with radial-gradients, moving the center down to the bottom of the page and increasing the radius, but either the spacing of the colors gets weird or the gradient blending turns to a hard line.

Any ideas how to make this happen? Can I warp the linear gradient with CSS? Is there a way I can do it with radial-gradient? SVG?

If you'd like to experiment with the prototype and see the effect I'm going for, [here you go](http://peoplesriverhistory.us/experiments/sky/).

Comment: any way you can show us an approximation of what you want?  I don't get the *think the darkening vignetting that happens in photographs of the sky*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `radial-gradient` you need to control the radius and make the horizontal one very big to get effect you want:

```css
html {
  min-height:300vh;
  background: radial-gradient(
      400% 100% at bottom, /* adjust the 400% to control the curve */
      #0e1a34, #5e7481, #a0947a, #c17a5c, #ada7cb, #d7e8fd, #d7edf0);
}
```

To have the same radius for all colors you can consider multiple background but it will be a bit tricky to get the correct fading:

```css
html {
  min-height:260vh;
  
  background: 
    radial-gradient(150% 90% at bottom,#0e1a34    ,#0e1a34,transparent) 0 100%,
    radial-gradient(150% 90% at bottom,transparent,#5e7481,transparent) 0 80%,
    radial-gradient(150% 90% at bottom,transparent,#a0947a,transparent) 0 60%,
    radial-gradient(150% 90% at bottom,transparent,#c17a5c,transparent) 0 40%,
    radial-gradient(150% 90% at bottom,transparent,#ada7cb,transparent) 0 20%,
    radial-gradient(150% 90% at bottom,transparent,#d7edf0,#d7edf0    ) 0 0%;
  background-size:100% 35%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Do you wanna test that before you post it?

Comment: @WesModes I never post something without testing, if this is not what you want, you need to make your question more clear and probably show the result you want to achieve

Comment: I asked because because my browser (latest version of chrome) ignored the CSS rule with and without the comments. "Invalid property value"

Comment: Perhaps you meant background-image?

Comment: @WesModes both will work the same, I am also using the last version of chrome and there is nothing special in the property I am using and it should work fine everywhere unless you made a typo when doing a copy/paste or when removing the comments

Comment: My mistake, a bit of bad commenting above, that left half a CSS rule.

Comment: Since it is radial, the colors at the bottom have a smaller radius, right? Anyway to make the colors all have a similar radius?

Comment: I wanted the curve upward, and so with the first idea, I changed it to: background: 

```radial-gradient(
      300% 100% at bottom, /* adjust the 400% to control the curve */
      #d7edf0, #d7e8fd, #ada7cb, #c17a5c, #a0947a, #5e7481, #0e1a34);```

Comment: With the second suggestion, how would you make it fit an arbitrary sized container?

Comment: @WesModes define the size using percentage and same for the position: https://jsfiddle.net/be928n6y/ ... the position need to go from 0% to 100% to cover all the area and you need to find the best value for the size to get a good result

Comment: @WesModes adjusted the answer to show a bottom configuration for both

Comment: I'm not a CSS novice, and the syntax of this is a mind bender. Still trying to work out everything.

Comment: What are the numbers after the parenthesis? Is that width and height as part of the background shortcut?

Comment: @WesModes it's background then its position `0 100%`--> `left 0 top 100%` --> `left 0 bottom 0`

Comment: @WesModes the width/height is set the same for all the background  so I made it outside the background shorthand

Comment: @WesModes if you want to understand the background-position and how it works with percentage check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Comment: The multiple gradients get a little weird in the middle. I think I'll stick with the relative simplicity and effectiveness of the first solution. Thanks. Check out the prototype I'm experimenting with here: http://peoplesriverhistory.us/experiments/sky/