# Center an image when displayed through css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image using only css, when the image is displayed using only css.

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
  .page-id-28 {
    background-image: url(http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/IMG_2019107_1853-1.jpg) !important;
    background-size: 890px !important;
  }
}
```

Tried using `url(foo) center;`

Didn't work.

Comment: if you will be doing `url(foo) center;` you need background and not background-image

Comment: ah, thanks. Let me try

Comment: Or you can use `background-position`

Comment: @TemaniAfif correct to center. Can i adjust top and bottom somehow too?

Comment: What do you mean? If you center it, it is in *center*

Comment: @Vepthy It's in the center of the page but not in center of the image. Can i use something else to move it down the page a bit

Comment: Do you want to center an `<img>` or `background-image`? As they said, use `background-position: center`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 you will find what you need to make any position you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-position` can be `center center` or `50% 50%` (i.e. different values for horizontal/vertical are possible). You'll also need `no-repeat`. In the snippet below I used a smaller image size to fit it into the space available here:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/400x180/fb8);
  background-size: 400px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```css
@media(max-width: 768px){
  .page-id-28 {
    background-image: url(http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/IMG_2019107_1853-1.jpg) !important;
    background-size: 890px !important;
    background-position: center;
  }
}
```