# CSS: how to create an infinitely-moving repeating linear gradient?

Tags: html, css, background, css-animations, linear-gradients

So basically, I am trying to create a progress bar. In this example, I will just change the colors I was using to `red`, `green` and `blue` instead since that's obviously easier to understand than a load of hex values. Effectively, what I am going for is for the progress bar to have this RGB gradient background that gives the impression the gradient is moving from left to right, to signify that there is still activity (i.e. that the site hasn't frozen). I've tried a few things, starting with just setting `background: linear-gradient(120deg, red, green, blue)` and animating the `background-position` CSS property to simulate the gradient moving. However, once at the end of the animation, the progress bar jumped from being mostly blue (i.e. the end of the gradient), right back to green...I then tried manually-reflecting the gradient in the form `rgbgr` - i.e. `background: linear-gradient(120deg, red, green, blue, green, red)` and, while this looks better, there is still jumpiness. Finally, I tried using the `repeating-linear-gradient` CSS function - i.e. `background: repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, red, green, blue, green, red)`. This is the closest to what I'm aiming for, but in the example, you can see the gradient colors 'jumping', rather than animating smoothly

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

*{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: #131313;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#bar {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, red,green,blue, green, red);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 400% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 3s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 3s linear infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 3s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bar" style="width: 50%"></div>
    <p>Downloading 5 of 10</p>
  </div>
```

I've seen this effect on many sites before, so I assume it's possible in CSS. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run the animation a bit longer before looping back.

```css
@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:-33% 50%} /* instead of 0% 50% */
}
```

I also changed the gradient angle to `90deg` because the initial value makes the start and end of the gradient not matching very well

```
/* instead of 120deg */
background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, red,green,blue, green, red);
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

*{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: #131313;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#bar {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, red,green,blue, green, red);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 400% 100%;
    animation: AnimationName 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:-33% 50%}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bar" style="width: 50%"></div>
    <p>Downloading 5 of 10</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome man. Simply setting the background position to -33% was enough. Weirdly, it doesn't seem to matter how many colours I used or what the angle of the gradient was...as long as the background x position was around -33%, it seemed to work...with 5 colour stops, 10, 12, whatever...

Comment: @CssProblem it won't work with any angle, only for 90deg .. related to understand the logic behind the numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, you're right - you seem to get a slightly brighter strike if the isn't horizontal - still, I guess in the example I was using (with about 14 colour stops at 120deg), it still looks pretty seemless to the human eye

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like below and it will work with any angle you want:

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.wrapper {
  --d:100px;
  --angle:120deg; 
  
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  background: #131313;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:50px;
  color: white;
  margin:5px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content:"";
  height: 100%;
  left:0;
  width:var(--w);
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;

  background: repeating-linear-gradient(var(--angle), red, green, blue, green, red var(--d));
  background-size: calc(var(--d)/sin(var(--angle))) 100%;
  animation: AnimationName 2s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: calc(var(--d)/sin(var(--angle))) 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="--w:50%;">
  Downloading 5 of 10
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="--w:70%;--d:200px;--angle:45deg;">
  Downloading 5 of 10
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="--w:80%;--d:50px;--angle:150deg;">
  Downloading 5 of 10
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail about `/* = sinus(angle) */` and how the `--sinus` value is arrived at?  Is there a formula to determine this based on angle? Thanks!

Comment: @RCNeil It is `sin(120)` where the `120` is in degrees, not radians.  (For those wondering, "sinus" is Latin for "sine", which is the full name for the `sin()` function in trigonometry.)