# Offset a background's start position 50%?

Tags: css

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, this question is asking about centering not positioning from the right.

Is there a way to set the start position of a background image to be 50% across it's container using CSS only?

```
background-position: 50% center;
```

This does not work as it positions the background image to be center and not starting at 50%.

```
background-position: 50vw center;
```

This does not work as it's based upon the viewport and not container.

Also note I cannot offset the div itself as I need that to be in it's current postion.

Comment: your answer is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 (read until the end because the pseudo element is probably the solution you want)

Comment: Answer not there.

Comment: you already read it fully and tried all the code there in only 1min? unless you are superman, you need at least 15min to read it all and probably more than 30min to try the codes and understand them.

Comment: Read that answer before positing my question.

Comment: If you can't find your answer in the duplicates, could you add some more detail of exactly what you want? (And how this situation is different from the dup's)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, like this:

```
.container {
  background-image: url('w3css.gif'); //insert your url ofcourse
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
```

Comment: afraid not, this sizes the background too small, does not position it

Comment: updated it, does it work now?

Comment: This answer is tested and works..

Comment: I doubt the desired effect is to squash the image (though I'm struggling to understand exactly what the asker is aiming for, so perhaps I'm wrong)

Comment: I can only base my answer on the info I have though..