# Move image some pixels with object-position

Tags: css

I am trying to "move" an image inside a `div` which is adjusted with `object-fit: cover;` and `object-position: center;`.

My question is: Can I move the center-positioned image a few pixels to the right without to remove the `object-*` from my css?

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.myDiv.before img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myDiv.after img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.general {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to NOT resize the image as in `.after`, but moving the image a few `px` right/left in the div. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply adjust the `object-position` value. The property works the same way as `background-position`

> The object-position property determines the alignment of the replaced element inside its box. The `<position>` value type (which is also used for background-position) is defined in [CSS-VALUES-3], and is resolved using the concrete object size as the object area and the content box as the positioning area. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-object-position)</sup>

Related question: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.myDiv.before img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myDiv.after img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
.myDiv.after.moved img  {
  object-position:calc(50% + 10px) 50%; /* the fix is here ! */
}

.general {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after moved">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do it with [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  /* Move the image left or right */
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* padding-right: 10px */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: blue;
}

.myDiv.before img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myDiv.after img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.general {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work, but my client wants to keep the `div` (and also, the image) dimension, which in this case would be 150x150. If I apply padding, it turns to 160x150, isn't it?

Comment: You can fix that by adding to the parent div `box-sizing: border-box`. I changed the answer above ^

Answer (score 0):

You can move the images by setting `left` or `right` css attribute on the `relative` position as follows on `<img>` tag.

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.myDiv.before img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}

.myDiv.after img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
}

.general {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your image dimension is not changing... Please have a look.

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.myDiv.before {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

.myDiv.before img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.myDiv.after img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.general {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please have a look...do you need like that way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If u inspect the first `div`, you can see the first image is "out" of the 'div'. Your answer might work tho, only if we could solve the first image problem

Answer (score 0):

You could just move the `img` inside your `div` like this:

`.myDiv img { position: relative; left: 10px; //or top, bottom, right }`

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  
  /* just for demo purpose */
  background-color: green;
}

.myDiv.before img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myDiv.after img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.general {
  display: flex;
}

.myDiv img {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="myDiv before">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv after">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```