# How to smoothly loop CSS gradient on text, so it appears to loop infinitely

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue looping this gradient over this text without an annoying jump appearing upon the animation looping. I'd like it to infinitely move across the next smoothly, so that annoying stutter isn't present. Any clue how I'd properly go about this?

 
[Here's a live example of my code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/kingpossum/pen/JjNMoqP),
and here's the corresponding HTML and CSS:

```html
<pre class="header">
88888888888 888    888 8888888888      8888888b.   .d88888b.   .d8888b.   .d8888b.  888     888 888b     d888      8888888b.  8888888888 888b    888
    888     888    888 888             888   Y88b d88P" "Y88b d88P  Y88b d88P  Y88b 888     888 8888b   d8888      888  "Y88b 888        8888b   888
    888     888    888 888             888    888 888     888 Y88b.      Y88b.      888     888 88888b.d88888      888    888 888        88888b  888
    888     8888888888 8888888         888   d88P 888     888  "Y888b.    "Y888b.   888     888 888Y88888P888      888    888 8888888    888Y88b 888
    888     888    888 888             8888888P"  888     888     "Y88b.     "Y88b. 888     888 888 Y888P 888      888    888 888        888 Y88b888
    888     888    888 888             888        888     888       "888       "888 888     888 888  Y8P  888      888    888 888        888  Y88888
    888     888    888 888             888        Y88b. .d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 888   "   888      888  .d88P 888        888   Y8888
    888     888    888 8888888888      888         "Y88888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888       888      8888888P"  8888888888 888    Y888
  </pre>
```

```css
.header{

  text-align: center;

  font-family: monospace;
  display:block;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%, #ff9a00 10%, #d1de21 20%, #4fdc4a 30%, #3fdad8 40%, #2fc9e2 50%, #1c7fee 60%, #5f15f2 70%, #ba0cf8 80%, #fb07d9 90%, #ff0000 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: move 35s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    to {
        background-position: 1600vh;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i'm thoroughly stumped. Thank you!

Comment: It's really hard to understand, I could barely understand you. Maybe your gradients are a lot and you can change the percentages.

Comment: is it just me or there is actually no annoying jump appearing upon the animation looping?

Comment: Set background-size to 200% or any value that is more than 100%. It should help.

Comment: use viewport width unstead of viewport height. (background-position: 100vw;) and play with animation duration. in your codePen the exact with is 100vw - 8px*2 (body LR margin). goodluck

Comment: That's exactly it, tdjprog!!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As the text is monospace we can define the width of that block in ch units.

Putting the text in an inner element (so it can be given the ch width but still be centered within the header) this snippet animates the background to go from left to right the width of the text (like in the original in the question, but less extreme distance). As it is repeated and it exactly goes back to the start there is no flicker.

```css
.header .inner{
  --len: 148ch;
  width: var(--len);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  display:block;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%, #ff9a00 10%, #d1de21 20%, #4fdc4a 30%, #3fdad8 40%, #2fc9e2 50%, #1c7fee 60%, #5f15f2 70%, #ba0cf8 80%, #fb07d9 90%, #ff0000 100%);
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    to {
        background-position: var(--len) 0, 0 0;
    }
}

body{
  background:#000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<pre class="inner">





88888888888 888    888 8888888888      8888888b.   .d88888b.   .d8888b.   .d8888b.  888     888 888b     d888      8888888b.  8888888888 888b    888
    888     888    888 888             888   Y88b d88P" "Y88b d88P  Y88b d88P  Y88b 888     888 8888b   d8888      888  "Y88b 888        8888b   888
    888     888    888 888             888    888 888     888 Y88b.      Y88b.      888     888 88888b.d88888      888    888 888        88888b  888
    888     8888888888 8888888         888   d88P 888     888  "Y888b.    "Y888b.   888     888 888Y88888P888      888    888 8888888    888Y88b 888
    888     888    888 888             8888888P"  888     888     "Y88b.     "Y88b. 888     888 888 Y888P 888      888    888 888        888 Y88b888
    888     888    888 888             888        888     888       "888       "888 888     888 888  Y8P  888      888    888 888        888  Y88888
    888     888    888 888             888        Y88b. .d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 888   "   888      888  .d88P 888        888   Y8888
    888     888    888 8888888888      888         "Y88888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888       888      8888888P"  8888888888 888    Y888</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of both gradients, the top one is using opaque colors and is repeated by default so we will never see the bottom layer: https://jsfiddle.net/v1jcLm0n/

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you are right of course, it was a leftover for when I was trying to reconcile the width of the overall header being different from the width of the actual text. Edited out.

Answer (score 0):

consider the following where you don't need any harcoded value:

```css
.header{
  font-family: monospace;
  display:inline-block;
  color:transparent;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff9a00 10%, #d1de21 20%, #4fdc4a 30%, #3fdad8 40%, #2fc9e2 50%, #1c7fee 60%, #5f15f2 70%, #ba0cf8 80%, #fb07d9 90%, #ff0000 100%)
    left/50% 100%; /* 50% = half the width*/
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position: right; /* you simply animate to right*/
  }
}

body {
  background:#000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<pre class="header">
88888888888 888    888 8888888888      8888888b.   .d88888b.   .d8888b.   .d8888b.  888     888 888b     d888      8888888b.  8888888888 888b    888
    888     888    888 888             888   Y88b d88P" "Y88b d88P  Y88b d88P  Y88b 888     888 8888b   d8888      888  "Y88b 888        8888b   888
    888     888    888 888             888    888 888     888 Y88b.      Y88b.      888     888 88888b.d88888      888    888 888        88888b  888
    888     8888888888 8888888         888   d88P 888     888  "Y888b.    "Y888b.   888     888 888Y88888P888      888    888 8888888    888Y88b 888
    888     888    888 888             8888888P"  888     888     "Y88b.     "Y88b. 888     888 888 Y888P 888      888    888 888        888 Y88b888
    888     888    888 888             888        888     888       "888       "888 888     888 888  Y8P  888      888    888 888        888  Y88888
    888     888    888 888             888        Y88b. .d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 888   "   888      888  .d88P 888        888   Y8888
    888     888    888 8888888888      888         "Y88888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888       888      8888888P"  8888888888 888    Y888
  </pre>
  
  <pre class="header" style="font-size:5px">
88888888888 888    888 8888888888      8888888b.   .d88888b.   .d8888b.   .d8888b.  888     888 888b     d888      8888888b.  8888888888 888b    888
    888     888    888 888             888   Y88b d88P" "Y88b d88P  Y88b d88P  Y88b 888     888 8888b   d8888      888  "Y88b 888        8888b   888
    888     888    888 888             888    888 888     888 Y88b.      Y88b.      888     888 88888b.d88888      888    888 888        88888b  888
    888     8888888888 8888888         888   d88P 888     888  "Y888b.    "Y888b.   888     888 888Y88888P888      888    888 8888888    888Y88b 888
    888     888    888 888             8888888P"  888     888     "Y88b.     "Y88b. 888     888 888 Y888P 888      888    888 888        888 Y88b888
    888     888    888 888             888        888     888       "888       "888 888     888 888  Y8P  888      888    888 888        888  Y88888
    888     888    888 888             888        Y88b. .d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 888   "   888      888  .d88P 888        888   Y8888
    888     888    888 8888888888      888         "Y88888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888       888      8888888P"  8888888888 888    Y888
  </pre>
```

Another variant:

```css
.header{
  font-family: monospace;
  display:inline-block;
  color:transparent;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000 0%, #ff9a00 10%, #d1de21 20%, #4fdc4a 30%, #3fdad8 40%, #2fc9e2 50%, #1c7fee 60%, #5f15f2 70%, #ba0cf8 80%, #fb07d9 90%, #ff0000 100%)
    left/200% 100%; /* 200% = twice the width*/
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  animation: move 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position: -200% 0; 
  }
}

body {
  background:#000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<pre class="header">
88888888888 888    888 8888888888      8888888b.   .d88888b.   .d8888b.   .d8888b.  888     888 888b     d888      8888888b.  8888888888 888b    888
    888     888    888 888             888   Y88b d88P" "Y88b d88P  Y88b d88P  Y88b 888     888 8888b   d8888      888  "Y88b 888        8888b   888
    888     888    888 888             888    888 888     888 Y88b.      Y88b.      888     888 88888b.d88888      888    888 888        88888b  888
    888     8888888888 8888888         888   d88P 888     888  "Y888b.    "Y888b.   888     888 888Y88888P888      888    888 8888888    888Y88b 888
    888     888    888 888             8888888P"  888     888     "Y88b.     "Y88b. 888     888 888 Y888P 888      888    888 888        888 Y88b888
    888     888    888 888             888        888     888       "888       "888 888     888 888  Y8P  888      888    888 888        888  Y88888
    888     888    888 888             888        Y88b. .d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 888   "   888      888  .d88P 888        888   Y8888
    888     888    888 8888888888      888         "Y88888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888       888      8888888P"  8888888888 888    Y888
  </pre>
  
  <pre class="header" style="font-size:5px">
88888888888 888    888 8888888888      8888888b.   .d88888b.   .d8888b.   .d8888b.  888     888 888b     d888      8888888b.  8888888888 888b    888
    888     888    888 888             888   Y88b d88P" "Y88b d88P  Y88b d88P  Y88b 888     888 8888b   d8888      888  "Y88b 888        8888b   888
    888     888    888 888             888    888 888     888 Y88b.      Y88b.      888     888 88888b.d88888      888    888 888        88888b  888
    888     8888888888 8888888         888   d88P 888     888  "Y888b.    "Y888b.   888     888 888Y88888P888      888    888 8888888    888Y88b 888
    888     888    888 888             8888888P"  888     888     "Y88b.     "Y88b. 888     888 888 Y888P 888      888    888 888        888 Y88b888
    888     888    888 888             888        888     888       "888       "888 888     888 888  Y8P  888      888    888 888        888  Y88888
    888     888    888 888             888        Y88b. .d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 888   "   888      888  .d88P 888        888   Y8888
    888     888    888 8888888888      888         "Y88888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888       888      8888888P"  8888888888 888    Y888
  </pre>
```

Related question to get more detail about the values: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)