# Change background image (color) from left to right like in a continuous motion

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

A toggle switch button in the top right toggles from light to dark mode and vice versa. The background is an image and zoomed in.

Currently, it moves from

- left to right when switched to dark mode
- right to left when switched to light mode

But I want it to move in one direction itself. Like, suppose it's in light mode, and when I switch it to dark mode the background image shifts to the right (**left > right**) like it's supposed to, and then when I switch it to light mode I want the background image to go from left to right again (**left > right**).

Kinda like a continuous loop but with a toggle button.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

I guess it might work with keyframes and animations not sure. But is there a way to do it in JS without the need for keyframes?

Don't mind the code below cause I had to clip it from my react project so some of the CSS property might not seem needed.

```js
let Dark = false
const DarkOrLight = () => {
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName('Login-container')[0]
  if (!Dark) {
    container.style.backgroundPosition = 'right'
  } else {
    container.style.backgroundPosition = 'left'
  }
  Dark = !Dark
}
```

```css
.toggle-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5%;
}

.toggle {
  appearance: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #383030 0%, #22282e 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.toggle::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(182, 244, 146), rgb(51, 139, 147));
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.toggle:checked {
  background-color: #b6f492;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #b6f492, rgb(51, 139, 147));
}

.toggle:checked::after {
  transform: translateX(23px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #383030 0%, #22282e 100%);
}

.Login-container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #b6f492, #338b93, #383030, #22282e);
  background-size: 400%;
  background-position: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  font-family: Merriweather;
}
```

```html
<div class="Login-container">
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" onClick=DarkOrLight()></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your distribution of colors currently looks like: `0....100|0....100|` instead you need to provide a way to ***come back home***: `0...100...0|0...100...0|`. The rest is pure math. In JS increment a variable `bgPos` by `1` on each click, and move it `background-position` left by `n% * bgPos`, where `n` depends on the number of your color-stops in relation to the lightModeColors (transitionColors) darkModeColors (transitionColors) .

Comment: And since you did not provided the colors gradients needed to ***come back home*** (to light mode) - it's pretty hard to answer. Also, as you're currently doing, your colors-stops are **off by one**! — since you use a background-size of 400%.

Comment: PS: the only culprit in your task is that, you need to take into consideration that: by moving a background-image in % (instead of px) 100% does not means that the background image will be back at its starting position. `100%` is exactly the same as setting it to `right`. Here's a very detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731106/using-percentage-values-with-background-position-on-a-linear-gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix your color-stops**:

- you have a background-size of **400%**
- but you use only **4** color-stops (**instead of 5**).

The problem: by simply animating left to right this happens with your current code:

```
|left                          right|       bg-position left-to-right
|#1         |#2         |#3         |#4     4 colors-stops 
|0%      |100%    |200%    |300%    |400%   bg-size
| light  |     (anim)      |  dark  |       mode
|░░░░░░░░|▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓|
```

Do you know what exact color is at 100%? ***No.***
Do you know what exact color is at 300%? ***No.***
See the **inconsistency**? The color stops are **off by one**.

Some **possible solutions to the above:**

- add one more color-stop -or
- reduce the width to 300% -or
- use CSS `linear-gradient()` stops at the [desired % position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)

### Suggestion

Animate a child element that has that desired background:

- Width of **400%**
- **5 color-stops**, where the last one matches the first!

```
|0%               |200%             |400%   animate left by -%
|#1      |#2      |#3      |#4      |#1     5 colors-stops 
|0%      |100%    |200%    |300%    |400%   width
| light  | (anim) |  dark  | (anim) |       mode 
|░░░░░░░░|▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓|▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|░░...
```

as you can see, on 400% we're back on color `#1` - ideal for the **loop logic**!  And by *"animate left by -%"* I mean animate the GPU accelerated `transform: translateX()` property value.

***But wait! What if I want to animate the background-position instead of an Element child?***
*Isn't `background-position: 100% 0`; exactly the same as `background-position: right 0`*?
[Sadly, yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731106/using-percentage-values-with-background-position-on-a-linear-gradient). 100% will not set it at its initial state (`0%`). The above table would make sense if we animated a child element to steps of -200% `left` position.
For an in-depth explanation of this (background-position) issue read: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731106/using-percentage-values-with-background-position-on-a-linear-gradient).

### Solution

You could either:

1. Use a child element (with the background) set to 4× the width of your parent element (`width: 400%;`). Then in JS, move it left by `-200%`, and on `transitionend` Event you could reset its position to 0 (if goin back to Light mode) using the Modulo (Reminder) operator `%`.
2. Otherwise, the math for moving the background is actually in thirds:

Formula: `100 / 3 * totModes * counter`
In the table below being `bgX = 100 / 3 * 2 * (1) = 66.66666666666667` etc...

```
|0%               |66.66%           |133.33% bg-position by %
|#1      |#2      |#3      |#4      |#1      5 colors-stops 
|0%      |100%    |200%    |300%    |400%    bg-size
| light  | (anim) |  dark  | (anim) |        mode 
|░░░░░░░░|▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓|▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|░░...
```

**Example:**

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const find = (selector, parent) => (parent || document).querySelector(selector);



// Task:

const elContainer = find("#login");
let c = 0; // position counter

const toggleDarkMode = () => {
  c += 1;
  const bgX = 100 / 3 * 2 * c;
  console.log(bgX)
  elContainer.style.backgroundPosition = `${bgX}%`;
};

find("#toggleMode").addEventListener("input", toggleDarkMode);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.Login-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
    #fff,
    red,
    #000,
    blue,
    #fff /*back to home*/
  );
  background-size: 400%;
  background-position: 0% 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle-container">
  DARK MODE: <input id="toggleMode" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
</label>
<div id="login" class="Login-container"></div>
```

### Diagonal gradients?

As you can see, the above will work only if the background-image's `linear-gradient()` is either set to `90deg`, `270deg`, `to right` or `to left`.

For Diagonal gradients **any other degrees** you could duplicate the values and move by half. But in that case the background-image should be positioned with negative offsets. And again, I think the `animationend` would finally come into play.

Not sure if the above helps, but hopefully it will clear some thoughts and help you find a viable solution.