# How to make an infinite sliding background-image?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make an infinite background animation that slides from right to left. This what I achieved so far:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5F5H2S2/background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: background-animation 5s linear infinite;
  animation: background-animation 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes background-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">hello</div>
```

It works pretty well, the problem is that after 5 seconds, the background goes back at its initial position, and then start a new animation.

What I want is that the background continues sliding from right to left forever. I can somewhat achieve this by multiplying the values of the animation-duration and the background-position, for example:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5F5H2S2/background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: background-animation 30s linear infinite;
  animation: background-animation 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes background-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 1000% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">hello</div>
```

But this is not super elegant and just delays the problem. Is there any clever way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use cover, rely on percentage size

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5F5H2S2/background.jpg');
  background-size: 300% auto; /* 300% here */
  animation: background-animation 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes background-animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 150% 50%; /* 150 = 300/2*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">hello</div>
```

Related: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)