# Height occupied by an upright letter if `line-height: 1`

Tags: css, text, typography

So I have some text which I make `upright` and I want to have a different `background` behind each letter.

For my actual use case, the list of backgrounds is randomly generated by a function that gets fed the number of letters.

Now the question is... **how much vertical space does a letter occupy?** I'm using a monospaced font here and I've set the `line-height` to `1` (this is a value I can pick, so I picked `1` thinking this would simplify things).

Here's a mock Sass version of the code:

```
$c: #448aff, #1565c0, #009688, #8bc34a, #ffc107, #ff9800, #f44336, #ad1457;
$n: length($c);
$m: .5*$n;
$l: ();

@for $i from 0 to $m {
    $l: $l, 
        conic-gradient(from random(360)*1deg 
                at random(100)*1% random(100)*1%, 
                nth($c, $i + 1), nth($c, $i + $m + 1), 
                nth($c, $i + 1))
            0 $i*1em
}

div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
    background: $l;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 1em;
    font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em)/ 1 monospace;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    text-transform: uppercase
}
```

So with a `line-height` of `1`, I would think a letter occupies `1lh` or `1em`... but that's not enough!

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
  background: 
    conic-gradient(from 37deg at 54% 48%, #448aff, #ffc107, #448aff), 
    conic-gradient(from 264deg at 8% 31%, #1565c0, #ff9800, #1565c0) 0 1em, 
    conic-gradient(from -61deg at 92% 2%, #009688, #f44336, #009688) 0 2em, 
    conic-gradient(from -5deg at 41% 95%, #8bc34a, #ad1457, #8bc34a) 0 3em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1em;
  font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em)/1 monospace;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<div>play</div>
```

**What am I missing? How much vertical space does a letter occupy in this scenario? How do I size and position my gradients so that I have one behind each letter?**

---

Splitting the text into letters, each wrapped in an element with its own `background` is absolutely NOT an option here. Not interested in that.

Comment: The amount of space is entirely a function of the font used as it's built into the glyph so there is no "one size fits all" answer here.

Comment: the line-height in such situation will control the horizontal space and no more the vertical space so I am afraid we will end with a font-related thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing with `line-height` won't work because it will adjust the horizontal space and not the vertical one

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
  font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em)/4 monospace;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<div>play</div>
```

So I think you are left with the default behavior of `1.2em` but not sure if you can rely on it since it depends on the font and the browser implementation

> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)</sup>

If you combine it with [the use of percentage on `background-position`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333), you will have only one value to "guess" so if you know the font-family it can work.

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
  background: 
    conic-gradient(from 37deg at 54% 48%, #448aff, #ffc107, #448aff) 0 calc(0*100%/3), 
    conic-gradient(from 264deg at 8% 31%, #1565c0, #ff9800, #1565c0) 0 calc(1*100%/3), 
    conic-gradient(from -61deg at 92% 2%, #009688, #f44336, #009688) 0 calc(2*100%/3), 
    conic-gradient(from -5deg at 41% 95%, #8bc34a, #ad1457, #8bc34a) 0 calc(3*100%/3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1.2em; /* you will have to adjust this */
  font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em)/1 monospace;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<div>play</div>
```

**Edit**: as per @Ana comment, we can also use percentage for the size and no more depend on font metrics

```css
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
  background: 
    conic-gradient(from 37deg at 54% 48%, #448aff, #ffc107, #448aff) 0 calc(0*100%/3), 
    conic-gradient(from 264deg at 8% 31%, #1565c0, #ff9800, #1565c0) 0 calc(1*100%/3), 
    conic-gradient(from -61deg at 92% 2%, #009688, #f44336, #009688) 0 calc(2*100%/3), 
    conic-gradient(from -5deg at 41% 95%, #8bc34a, #ad1457, #8bc34a) 0 calc(3*100%/3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% calc(100%/4); 
  font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em)/1 monospace;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<div>play</div>
```

---

This said, you can create the same thing differently. A bit hacky but it can be a good workaround:

```css
div {
  width: 1ch; /* limit the width to one character */
  word-break: break-all; /* allow the word to break */
  /* you can use 1lh everywhere */
  background: 
    conic-gradient(from 37deg at 54% 48%, #448aff, #ffc107, #448aff), 
    conic-gradient(from 264deg at 8% 31%, #1565c0, #ff9800, #1565c0) 0 1lh, 
    conic-gradient(from -61deg at 92% 2%, #009688, #f44336, #009688) 0 2lh, 
    conic-gradient(from -5deg at 41% 95%, #8bc34a, #ad1457, #8bc34a) 0 3lh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1lh;
  /* you can use percentage with background-position as well
  background-position:
   0 calc(0*100%/3),
   0 calc(1*100%/3),
   0 calc(2*100%/3),
   0 calc(3*100%/3); */
  font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em)/1 monospace;
  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-inline: .2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<div>play</div>
<div style="line-height: 2">play</div>
<div style="line-height: .9">play</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, ended up using the tactic of the `25%` height backgrounds positioned at `i*100%/(n - 1)`. And question: didn't you once write an article detailing how those `%` values are computed? Maybe you could link to it so others who come across this aren't confused about why it's `100%/3` and not `100%/4` when there are `4` letters/ backgrounds. I know the formula and how to compute it, but pretty sure not everyone does.

Comment: @Ana it's actually an SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333) that I link in all my articles. And yes, the 25% height should be perfect! I should have thought about it as well since you already know the number of letters.

Answer (score 1):

Using `word-break` also works, especially if you want to keep the gradient backgrounds square with larger line heights.

```css
div {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px;
background: 
    conic-gradient(from 37deg at 54% 48%, #448aff, #ffc107, #448aff) 0 calc(0 * 100% / 3),
    conic-gradient(from 264deg at 8% 31%, #1565c0, #ff9800, #1565c0) 0 calc(1 * 100% / 3),
    conic-gradient(from -61deg at 92% 2%, #009688, #f44336, #009688) 0 calc(2 * 100% / 3),
    conic-gradient(from -5deg at 41% 95%, #8bc34a, #ad1457, #8bc34a) 0 calc(3 * 100% / 3);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% calc(100% / 4);
font: 900 clamp(1em, 18vmin, 18em) / 1.5 monospace;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-inline: calc((1lh - 1em) / 2);
width: 1em;
text-align: center;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>play</div>
```