# In React, or just pure css, how can I have multiple backgrounds on a body tag, but only animate one?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, background

I'm authoring a long page in React (with Tailwind), and I want to stack three different backgrounds on top of each other. Two of the backgrounds are static svgs; one is a gradient that should animate.

I can stack the backgrounds like this:

```
body { 
   background: url("/i/static_bg_1.svg"), url("/i/static_bg_2.svg"), linear-gradient(#000, #555, #999);
}
```

And I can add animation to the background, like this:

```
body { 
   animation: gradient-animation 4s ease infinite;

   @keyframes gradient-animation {
      0% {
        background-position: 50% 0px;
      }
      50% {
        background-position: 100% 0px;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 50% 0px;
      }
   }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do something like this pseudo-code:

```
body { 
   background: url("/i/static_bg_1.svg"), url("/i/static_bg_2.svg"), linear-gradient(#000, #555, #999);
   background-animation: none, none, gradient-animation
}
```

I need all of the elements to span the whole long page, not just the active viewport. Any suggestions are welcome; React/JSX is fine, doesn't need to be css only.

Thanks -

Comment: `background-position: 0 0,0 0, 50% 0` and so on

Comment: and you gradient won't animate if you don't give it a size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333